# Chrome extension breaks when tab is changed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that simulates a keypress to submit a form. This works great as long as I stay on the page and do not switch tabs. When I switch tab the form doesn't get fill out the same.

What's strange is that it's the `replaceCommentHtmlAndSetSender` function that doesn't seem to propagate information properly on after one comment has been submitted and keypress event is fired. If I click back in to the page then the extension works.

I've tried viewing all events in the console using `monitorEvents(window)` and they seem to be the same. I've also tried adding a `window.focus()` event in `replaceCommentHtmlAndSetSender` without luck.

What events / differences could leaving the tab lead to this behavior?

```
var replaceCommentHtmlAndSetSender = function(reply_link, resp, id) {
  $(document.activeElement).sendkeys("txt")
  setTimeout(function() {
    var str = '<span data-text="true" data-comment-sender="true">txt >/span>'
    $(document.activeElement).replaceWith(str)
  })
  submitComment()
}

var submitComment = function() {
  var foundElementScript = document.createElement("script")
  foundElementScript.textContent = "foundElement()"
  document.head.appendChild(foundElementScript)
  foundElementScript.parentNode.removeChild(foundElementScript)
}

// this script is injected into the page
function foundElement(){
    found=document.querySelectorAll('[data-comment-sender="true"]')[0];
    found.setAttribute("data-comment-sender", "false");
    submitComment(found);
  }
}

function submitComment(element) {
  var event;

  if(document.createEvent) {
    event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent('keydown', true, true);
  } else {
    event = document.createEventObject();
    event.eventType = 'keydown';
  }

  event.eventName = 'keydown';
  event.keyCode = 13;
  event.which = 13;

  if(document.createEvent) {
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  } else {
    element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you wrapping your jQuery function in a $( document ).ready?  That might be the root cause since you code might be running before new documents are loaded.